# failed to open Hibernate session for data transfer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

After switching from JDBC to Hibernate, one of the DAO classes that I rewrote to Hibernate stopped connecting to the database and produces a similar error

```
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

I can’t find a solution myself, but the great Internet is silent. the second class written in JDBC works great!

**here is the class itself:**

```
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import killjoy.models.Book;
import killjoy.models.Person;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class PersonDAO {
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public PersonDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Person> index(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        return session.createQuery("select p from Person p", Person.class).getResultList();
    }

    public Person show(int id){
        return null;
    }

    public void save(Person person){
    }

    public void update(int id, Person updatePerson){
    }

    public void delete(int id){
    }

    public List<Book> getBook(int id){
        return null;
    }
```

**SpringConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("killjoy")
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext, Environment env) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.driver_class"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
    protected Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("killjoy");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer:**

```
public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(aServletContext);
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(aServletContext);
    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
                new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*");
    }

}
```

Comment: What is in your `hibernate.properties`. Also you want to rename it to something else as `hibernate.properties` is also automatically loaded by Hibernate. Finally please add the full stacktrace and not the snippet.